# Пересобрать массив

Tags: массивы, php

Здравсвуйте есть массив с n кол-вом элементов
[
0=>1
1=>3
2=>4
3=>5
...
]

нужно общее решение чтобы он был вида
[
1=>1
2=>3
3=>4
4=>5
...
]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так?

```
$arr = array(1, 3, 4, 5);
$result = array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), array_values($arr));
print_r($result);
# Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )
```

Comment: лишь в том случае если известно количество элементов, я же его не знаю, да даже если бы и знал если 140 например..
 можно конечно заполнить массив ключей тупо числами. но я уверен есть менее радиклаьный путь

Comment: Данному решению все равно, сколько элементов в исходном массиве.  
Что вы хотите сделать? Получить массив, где нумерация ключей начнется с 1, а не с 0? Или сгенерировать массив где ключ=>значение это определенная последовательность?

Comment: конкретно сейчас,да, где нумерация ключей начнется с 1.

Comment: @Михаил2342, вы проверили работоспособность предложенного решения? Оно вас удовлетворяет?

Comment: `array_unshift($arr,'');unset($arr[0]);`